# How to perform proof of work on the client?

Tags: node, pow, confirmation, ternary, client-library

I want to create a block that fulfill the Proof of Work requirement. After reading sparse documentation my understanding on how to do it is:

1- Serialize the block(message) excluding the 8-byte Nonce and compute the BLAKE2b-256 hash of this. Convert the hash into its 192-trit b1t6 encoding

2- Propose a random 8-byte Nonce and convert it into its 48-trit b1t6 encoding and append it to the hash trits.

3- Add a padding of three zero trits to create a 243-trit string.

4- Compute the Curl-P-81 hash of the 243-trit string.

5- Count the number of trailing zero trits in the hash.

6- Then, the PoW score equals 3<sup>#zeros</sup> / size(message).

7- If the PoW score is smaller than the minPowScore of the [node info](https://api.testnet.shimmer.network/api/core/v2/info) repeat the process from step 2, else the proposed nonce is sufficient to fulfill Proof of work.

My question is: is this procedure the correct one to fulfill Proof of work on the client. If it is the correct one, where can i get Curl-P-81 function or do step 4.
I have followed this [tip](https://github.com/iotaledger/tips/blob/main/tips/TIP-0012/tip-0012.md), but i can not find the Curl-P hashing function.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that Curl-P is still used here (with all the move to binary and the new ternary Troika hash), but presumably Curl-P proof of work has been implemented on many devices (e.g. GPU accelerated versions) and they did not want to see that time wasted.

The reference implementation of Curl-P (now used on the nodes) is [written in Rust](https://github.com/iotaledger/crypto.rs/tree/dev/src/hashes/ternary/curl_p). There is also an implementation of the hash function [in Java](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota-java/blob/dev/jota/src/main/java/org/iota/jota/pow/JCurl.java), which was used by the Android app before they switched to Trinity app.

There are also optimized Curl-P PoW implementations (which are optimized to finding a hash and not to hashing a single value), known under the name [PearlDiver](https://github.com/iotaledger/PearlDiver/blob/master/src/cfb/pearldiver/PearlDiver.java) (links to the Java reference implementation by Sergey Ivangelo also known as Come-From-Beyond). A WebGL implementation of PearlDiver is in the repo of [the old curl.js library](https://github.com/iotaledger/curl.lib.js/blob/master/src/pearldiver.js)